# spring cloud oauth sso without authorize step

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I have a spring cloud oauth @EnableAuthorizationServer that uses a jpa backend to store the accounts. I also have a couple of different clients, a website, an intranet and a ionic mobile app.

all the clients have separate client credentials inline in the oauth config block.

i have then tried to use the spring cloud sso to not have to login again.

my problem is that I want to remove the authorize step since all my clients are known to me and i simply want the user to be logged in across all my apps.

is this possible with spring cloud sso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization happens on the authorization server (so nothing to do with Spring Cloud). A `UserApprovalHandler` would do what you need, but the default one should work if you just set `autoapprove=true` (or a pattern matching te scopes you want to auto approve) in the client details. (Assuming your auth server is Spring OAuth.)